# Allow client to view/pritn pdf file stored on file system of server using website

Tags: c#, pdf

My requirement is to let client  view/print pdf files from folder and that folder is on server and file stored in this folder manually i.e. saving files in that folder . How I can live/share that folder so that client can view/print pdf files using website  . how to keep check on permissions etc. 
I have no idea how to do it .....

any guidance link ...

thanks in advance ......

Comment: Check for active directory user permissions?

Answer (score 0):

below is a brief idea since it's not clear what you want exactly

get the files from server 
use a ftp server to keep files and you can connect to server and get files via ftp
then you can print

if you are using normal windows server you need to run a service to return file 
create a client to connect to your service in the server and get the files
print it

Comment: thanks @kassapa for reply . printing will be done using website and files will be stored on server's folder (window server) .no idea how to go . any other way like cloud , ftp ,database+folder etc ....

Comment: Connect to the file server from your web site. Load file data to web site. Display Pdf on your web site. User can print using browser print options.